# A deleted module is appearing in getEditable('core.extension')

Tags: installation

Using Drupal core 8.9.6, created a custom module called `wdocsApi`. I wanted to rename it, so I uninstalled it and created `wdocs_api`. The problem is, when I try to install the new one, I get the error

> Drupal\Core\Extension\Exception\UnknownExtensionException: The module wdocsApi does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Extension\ExtensionList->getPathname() (line 522 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ExtensionList.php).

I tracked it down to `Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php` where a call is made to `$extension_config = \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('core.extension');` and my old module is returned in the list of modules.

What can I do to erase any remnants of the old one from my database?

Comment: I question your diagnosis. How did you "rename" the module? And of course, did you clear your caches?

Comment: I renamed the directory under custom modules, and renames the files that started with wdocsApi. I did clear all caches.

Comment: Related, which is why of course you had to rename it I guess: [Naming and placing your Drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/naming-and-placing-your-drupal-module#s-name-your-module). The machine name *must contain only lower-case letters and underscores.*

Answer (score 3):

There is many reasons for this and most likely the rename hapend before was completely uninstalled...

Here is a few examples of how to make sure its gone for good:

---

run the following somewhere

```
 \Drupal::service('module_installer')->uninstall(['wdocsApi']);
```

or Just

1. run `drush cex` to export the active config
2. Open up `core.extension.yml`  and delete the reference to  "wdocsApi"
3. run `drush cim` to import the config

Comment: Thanks taggartJ; worked like a charm, just what I needed. Another Drupal 8 mystery solved.

Comment: You can also copy the module back to its old name, uninstall it and delete the copy.